# How can I store Session values in Sinatra using Redis?

Tags: ruby, redis, sinatra

I'm trying to set up a cluster with Sinatra and Redis, and I need to store session values on redis for this to work, but I can't find the documentation.

Anyone knows how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to enable sessions in Sinatra, and save whatever values you need from that session object to redis using the set function.

```
enable :sessions
redis.set("session_value", session[:value])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a session object you can access e.g.

```
get "/bar" do
  session["hello"] = hello
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is more detailed answer. I think that is very simple to use Sinatra and Redis.

Add Redis gem to application. If you are using `Gemfile` just add it there.

```
gem 'redis'
```

Next you should manage Redis URL in your application:

```
ENV['REDIS_URL'] ||= 'redis://localhost:6379'
# Redis configuration
RedisURI = URI.parse(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
```

Here if `REDIS_URL` isn't set up application will use localhost. For production deployments you should set it to actual production Redis server.

Next is to parse it:

```
REDIS = Redis.new(host: RedisURI.host, port: RedisURI.port, password: RedisURI.password)
```

The `REDIS` constant is Redis connection you may work with.

```
REDIS.set(param, value) # Set some param to value
REDIS.get(:description) # get description key
```

In your case you should use unique key for each client. You can handle cookies of client via Sinatra's methods:

```
response.set_cookie(:foo, 'bar')
request.cookies[:foo]
response.delete_cookie(:foo)
```

Play with this code and it will be very clear...

You also may implement session [expire](http://redis.io/commands/expire) in Redis.